# Flexbox column layout does not wrap

Tags: css, flexbox

I am quite a newcomer in flexbox css.
I have a div that contains some "cells" (divs), please see following markup:

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my css (scss):

```
.outer {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 5px solid black;
}

.inner {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  width: 200px;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-basis: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
  @for $i from 1 through 9 {
    &:nth-child(#{$i}){
      border: 3px solid rgb(random(255),random(255),random(255));
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that I can't make the cells wrap when they reach the end of the available space in the wrapper div. Am I missing something?

Comment: I am going to make a guess here that you actually want the direction to be row, in other words horizontal. That would put 2/3 items on a row depending on margins and padding and such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this rule `height: 100%;` is missing in your `.inner` css declaration set. Otherwise the browser doesn't know when to "start wrapping" :)

Comment: OMG I feel so dumb :D
It was really that simple! Thanks!